# Stop Jumbling Up My Desktop Icons

Tags: windows

Is there a way to stop Windows(10) from jumbling my desktop icons on bootup? It seems to happen on about every fifth bootup or so.

Comment: What do you mean by jumbling your icons? That's not really specific or anything.